# Query String Filtering with Datatables in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatable, laravel-5.4

im using [YajraBox](https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master) for Datatables, it is Laravel extension.

I want to make it work with my Query String Filtering, so idea is tah **i need to pass search request to ajax request**

This is part of my form imput:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/lots?make%5B%5D=TOYOTA
```

So result have to be: only lots made by TOYOTA

This is my script for datatables with YajraBox:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#table').DataTable({
                bInfo: false,
                searching: false,
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                ajax: '{{  url("/data") }}',
                columns: [
                    { data: 'date', name: 'date' },
                    { data: 'bid', name: 'bid' },
                    { data: 'auction_name', name: 'auction_name' },
                    { data: 'pics_urls', name: 'pics_urls' },
                    { data: 'company', name: 'company' },
                    { data: 'model_name_en', name: 'model_name_en' },
                    { data: 'model_type_en', name: 'model_type_en' },
                    { data: 'grade_en', name: 'grade_en' },
                    { data: 'mileage_en', name: 'mileage_en' },
                    { data: 'model_year_en', name: 'model_year_en' },
                    { data: 'color_en', name: 'color_en' },
                    { data: 'displacement', name: 'displacement' },
                    { data: 'transmission_en', name: 'transmission_en' },
                    { data: 'scores_en', name: 'scores_en' },
                    { data: 'start_price_en', name: 'start_price_en' },
                    { data: 'result_en', name: 'result_en' }
                ]
            });
        });
    </script>
```

This is my controllers for view and for ajax:

```
public function index()
    {
        return view('lots.browse');
    }

    public function indexData(LotFilters $filters)
    {
       $lots  = Lot::filter($filters);

        return Datatables::eloquent($lots)->make(true);
    }
```

So what i think, i need to pass some howe `?make%5B%5D=TOYOTA` to ajax request  `ajax: '{{  url("/data") }}',`, any one know how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this like:

```
"{{ url('/data') }}" + "?make="+value  // where value contains TOYOTA in it
```

and get this value in controller like:

```
Input::get('make');
```

Comment: Wow,  can you show me how i can put input?  Do i have to use this facades: `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;` ?

Comment: For using `Input`, you have to `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;`. I just forget to mention this in the answser

Comment: Can you please show me how the controller will look?  Sorry for it. Im newbie.  I try like this: `$lots  = Lot::filter($filters)->withInput(Input::all());`  but it didn't work

Comment: i figure it out !! Thank you!!

Comment: @DmitryMalys a little bit busy, good to know that you have solve it :)

Comment: Do you have any ideas how i can get the whole Input and put it in var? because some times request can look like this : `?make%5B%5D=ACURA&model%5B%5D=LEGEND&score%5B%5D=6&auction%5B%5D=JCRA&auction%5B%5D=JU+Fukuoka&auction%5B%5D=JU+Hokkaido`